# How do I display a "No Results" message for each input parameter in OBIEE BIP RTF?

Tags: rtf, obiee, bi-publisher

Suppose I have 3 input parameters in my OBIEE data model: A, B, C.

Suppose the SQL query only returns results for parameter A. Thus, my XML only has results for A.

In my RTF word document, I want to display a "No Results" message for parameters B and C. How do I do this?

I am able to access ALL of the input parameters A, B, and C. But I'm not sure how to "search" for them in the XML.

I am on OBIEE 12c and Informix 11g.

Answer (score 0):

BIP does have a "count" function, which takes and xpath, and returns the count of children at that node. You could check if the count returned is zero, and print and error there.

Ref [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/bip/BIPRD/GUID-30710EE5-ED97-4489-8E48-642BCACD1837.htm#BIPRD2788) , [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2235832) and [here](http://cleartext.blogspot.com/2016/06/bip-distinct.html). It is not properly docuemnted, as it is a standard XSL function.

Comment: Thank you. How do I loop through the parameters, they are stored like this: [A,B,C,D]? Should I ask this in a new question.

Comment: Refer your parameter using <$PARAMETER_NAME> , note the $ sign.https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlpublisher/get-your-parameters-here,-guv. BIP has string manipulation functions. But no split function